# How do you automatically renew certs in pfSense?

Tags: ssl, certificate, pfsense

I have an internal certificate authority configured in pfSense that issues a certificate for webConfigurator. The certficate can be renewed from the certificate manager interface. How can the renewal process automated or accomplished from the shell.

[image]

Comment: The reason you have to manually renew the certificate is because you are not using a certificate bot solution.  [One such solution is Let's Encrypt.](https://forum.netgate.com/topic/139729/automated-cert-renewal) A better solution, set the expiration of the certificate for 25 years, since the certificate is self-signed you have to manually trust it and there is virtually no security threat to properly sized certificates.  When and If that changes, you generate a new certificate, and revoke the previously create certificate.

Comment: @Ramhound since when it is possible to properly revoke a self signed certificate?

Comment: @Ramhound No, that's not a solution. This is a private network and I'm not going to buy a public domain name to automate something that could be automated with a drinking bird toy. Browsers like Chrome (and I assume Firefox) do not accept certificates that are valid for more than 398 days.

Comment: @Chris_F - Your statement about Chrome not accepting certificates valid for more than 398 is false, you can look at virtually any TLS certificate that isn't signed by the Let's Encrypt Root CA, and you will find the root certificate is valid for longer than that amount of time.  The certificate for the website itself is only valid between 1 and 3 years due to standard operating procedures, based on the type of certificate you purchase, but since you are already installing the certificate into the certificate store the "valid to" date can be longer than 398 days.

Comment: @Ramhound Chrome doesn't give a hoot how long a root CA or intermediate CA's certificate is good for, I was obviously talking about leaf certificates, of which I am not wrong about. https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/net/docs/certificate_lifetimes.md

Comment: @Chris_F - I stand corrected.

Comment: @Ramhound Not so fast. Chrome is not complaining about a 10 year cert I just issued. I did some more searching and I've found some people claim that this restriction only applies to publicly rooted CAs. My question is how does Chrome tell the difference when my internal root CA cert is installed on this machine same as any other root CA. I can only imagine this works if Chrome maintains it's own list of root CAs to consider "public".

Comment: @Chris_F - Chrome only trusts the Root CA certificates the OS trusts. The explanation as to the determination was provided by Google.  “This only applies to the set of CAs that are trusted by default by Google Chrome, and not CAs that are operated by an enterprise and that have no certification paths to CAs that are trusted by default.” - Any Root CA certificate you manually install would apply to that statement. Yes; Google, Apple, Microsoft all keep a list of trusted Root CA so they can immediately revoke a compromised mainstream Root CA certificate. The list is very small.

Comment: I also need a solution for Certs to AUTO RENEW on expiration. One example is for  OpenVPN Certificates. If they expire the OpenVPN client refuses to connect. Anyone found a solution to automate what I do manaully on a certificate, which is click 2 buttons..